# GenServer with 1 HTTP request per second

Tags: elixir

I have made this genserver

```
defmodule Recorder do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(args) do
    id = Map.get(args, :id)
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args, name: id)
  end

  def init(state) do
    schedule_fetch_call()
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:jpeg_fetch, state) do
    spawn(fn ->
      IO.inspect("I am being called")
      IO.inspect(DateTime.utc_now())
      Fincher.request(:get, state.url) |> IO.inspect()
    end)
    schedule_fetch_call()
    {:noreply, Map.put(state, :run, true)}
  end

  defp schedule_fetch_call do
    Process.send_after(self(), :jpeg_fetch, 1000)
  end
end
```

I am running it 1 request per second with such a state.

```
  defp get_children do
    Enum.map([
      %{
        id: :hdipc,
        url: "http://77.66.206.55/jpgmulreq/1/image.jpg?key=1516975535684&lq=1&COUNTER"
      }
    ], fn(camera) ->
      Supervisor.child_spec({Recorder, camera}, id: camera.id)
    end)
  end
```

in the `application.ex`.

I am using spawn here but I don't want to use spawn, what is the most logical and ideal way to solve this problem.

1. where GenServer will make a request each second.
2. Also don't wait for the request to complete, as the request can take more than a second.
3. There are a few other certain operations I want to do in case of HTTP request-response.

I don't want to make genserver exhausted and crash. but to handle the back pressure of requests, which will be going each second (Not genstage as demand is not certain).

Is it possible to use `GenServer` in such a way that it can run without spawn and handle requests? any guidance or help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a perfect use-case for [`DynamicSupervisor`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html?).

Define the worker as a `GenServer` to perform a work.

```rb
defmodule Recorder.Worker do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(opts) do
    {id, opts} = Map.pop!(opts, :id)
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: id)
  end

  def init(state) do
    schedule_fetch_call()
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:jpeg_fetch, state) do
    result = Fincher.request(:get, state.url)
    schedule_fetch_call()
    {:noreply, Map.put(state, :run, {DateTime.utc_now(), result})}
  end

  defp schedule_fetch_call,
    do: Process.send_after(self(), :jpeg_fetch, 1000)
end
```

Then define a `DynamicSupervisor` as

```rb
defmodule Recorder.Supervisor do
  use DynamicSupervisor

  def start_link(opts),
    do: DynamicSupervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: __MODULE__)

  def start_child(opts),
    do: DynamicSupervisor.start_child(__MODULE__, {Recorder.Worker, opts})

  @impl DynamicSupervisor
  def init(opts),
    do: DynamicSupervisor.init(strategy: :one_for_one, extra_arguments: [opts])
end
```

Now start as many `DynamicSupervisor`s, also supervised, as you need.

---

I believe I have already recommended my `Tarearbol` library that (besides everything else,) simplifies the above with [Dynamic Workers Management](https://hexdocs.pm/tarearbol/dynamic_workers_management.html#content) to somewhat like

```rb
defmodule Recorder.Worker do
  use Tarearbol.DynamicManager

  def children_specs do
    Enum.into([%{id: :hdipc, url: "..."}], %{}, &{&1.id, &1})
  end

  def perform(_id, state) do
    result = Fincher.request(:get, state.url)
    {:noreply, Map.put(state, :run, {DateTime.utc_now(), result})}
  end
end
```

With it, `perform/2` will be executed after `timeout` option (defaulted to 1 second,) and one might also handle response timeouts with [`handle_timeout/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/tarearbol/Tarearbol.DynamicManager.html#c:handle_timeout/1).

Examples [from tests](https://github.com/am-kantox/tarearbol/blob/v1.1.1/test/dynamic_manager_test.exs) might be examined for inspiration.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to start it with a state as in `[%{id: :google, url: "google.com", %{id: :evercam, url: "evercam.io"}}]` ?

Comment: How to start what? The top-level supervisor starts `DynamicSupervisor`s; each supervisor starts workers. I am not sure I completely got the topology you are trying to achieve, but the main idea is to use `DynamicSupervisor` instead of the `GenServer` and `GenServer` instead of `spawn/1`.

Comment: I have added this in my `application.ex`'s start's children, `{DynamicSupervisor, strategy: :one_for_one, name: Recording.Supervisor}`

now, I am doing this to start it `DynamicSupervisor.start_child(RecordingSupervisor, {Recording.Worker, %{id: :hdipc, url: "http://77.66.206.55/jpgmulreq/1/image.jpg?key=1516975535684&lq=1&COUNTER"}})` from terminal, my question is, how I can just do it in a module so it will start with `iex -S mix`

Comment: The best place would be probably [`Application.start_phase/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html?#c:start_phase/3).

Comment: Or another supervisor where I will fetch all the urls from DB and pass them to start child.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it should start after the dynamic one.

Comment: Hi, I have found some issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65502503/how-to-make-request-per-second-without-waiting-for-previous-one-to-complete-in-g