# how to make request per second without waiting for previous one to complete in GenServer Elixir

Tags: elixir

[GenServer with 1 HTTP request per second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446116/genserver-with-1-http-request-per-second)

This is related to the above question, So I have posted the link.

I have made such GenServer worker.

this my whole GenServer

```
defmodule Recording.Worker do
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link(opts) do
    {id, opts} = Map.pop!(opts, :id)
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opts, name: id)
  end

  def init(state) do
    schedule_fetch_call(state.sleep)
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:jpeg_fetch, state) do
    {for_jpeg_bank, running} =
      make_jpeg_request(state.camera)
      |> running_map()

    IO.inspect("request")
    IO.inspect(DateTime.utc_now())
    put_it_in_jpeg_bank(for_jpeg_bank, state.camera.name)
    schedule_fetch_call(state.sleep)
    {:noreply, Map.put(state, :running, running)}
  end

  def get_state(pid) do
    GenServer.call(pid, :get)
  end

  def handle_call(:get, _from, state),
    do: {:reply, state, state}

  defp schedule_fetch_call(sleep),
    do: Process.send_after(self(), :jpeg_fetch, sleep)

  defp make_jpeg_request(camera) do
    headers = get_request_headers(camera.auth, camera.username, camera.password)
    requested_at = DateTime.utc_now()
    Everjamer.request(:get, camera.url, headers)
    |> get_body_size(requested_at)
  end

  defp get_body_size({:ok, %Finch.Response{body: body, headers: headers, status: 200}}, requested_at) do
    IO.inspect(headers)
    {body, "9", requested_at}
  end

  defp get_body_size(_error, requested_at), do: {:failed, requested_at}

  defp running_map({body, file_size, requested_at}),
    do:
      {%{datetime: requested_at, image: body, file_size: file_size},
       %{datetime: requested_at}}

  defp running_map({:failed, requested_at}), do: {%{}, %{datetime: requested_at}}

  defp get_request_headers("true", username, password),
    do: [{"Authorization", "Basic #{Base.encode64("#{username}:#{password}")}"}]

  defp get_request_headers(_, _username, _password), do: []

  defp put_it_in_jpeg_bank(state, process) do
    String.to_atom("storage_#{process}")
    |> Process.whereis()
    |> JpegBank.add(state)
  end
end
```

I am trying to make an HTTP request per second. even while using GenSever and starting it with a DynamicSupervisor such as

```
General.Supervisor.start_child(Recording.Worker, %{id: String.to_atom(detailed_camera.name), camera: detailed_camera, sleep: detailed_camera.sleep})
```

this part

```
  def handle_info(:jpeg_fetch, state) do
    {for_jpeg_bank, running} =
      make_jpeg_request(state.camera)
      |> running_map()

    IO.inspect("request")
    IO.inspect(DateTime.utc_now())
    put_it_in_jpeg_bank(for_jpeg_bank, state.camera.name)
    schedule_fetch_call(state.sleep)
    {:noreply, Map.put(state, :running, running)}
  end
```

still waiting for the previous request to complete and it becomes (the time request took to get complete) / per request not request per second.

the results of IO.inspect are such as

```
"request"
~U[2020-12-30 05:27:21.466262Z]
"request"
~U[2020-12-30 05:27:24.184548Z]
"request"
~U[2020-12-30 05:27:26.967173Z]

"request"
~U[2020-12-30 05:27:29.831532Z]
```

is there any way possible in Elixir that without using spawn, `handle_info` just keep running without waiting for the previous request or previous method to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One might start the `Supervisor` carrying two children: the `DynamicSupervisor` process and the process that would spawn workers. The latter would spawn a worker once per second and immediately reschedule.

#### Main Supervisor

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link(),
    do: Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)

  @impl Supervisor
  def init(nil) do
    children = [
      {DynamicSupervisor, strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.DS},
      {MyApp.WorkerStarter, [%{sleep: 1_000}]}
    ]

    Supervisor.init(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

#### Worker Starter

```rb
defmodule MyApp.WorkerStarter do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(opts) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, opts)
  end

  def init(state) do
    schedule_fetch_call(state)
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:request, state) do
    schedule_fetch_call(state.sleep)
    DynamicSupervisor.start_child(MyApp.DS, {MyApp.Worker, [state])
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  defp schedule_fetch_call(state),
    do: Process.send_after(self(), :request, state.sleep)
end
```

#### Worker

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Worker do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(state), 
    do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state)
  
  def init(state) do
    perform_work(state)
    {:stop, :normal}
  end

  defp perform_work(state), do: ...
```

Comment: is it possible to do this `{MyApp.WorkerStarter, [%{sleep: 1_000}]}` by user, in the previous approach when anyone adds a new camera.  I just start it as
`Supervisor.start_child(Recording.Worker, %{id: String.to_atom(detailed_camera.name), camera: detailed_camera, sleep: detailed_camera.sleep})` now I see this will not start with user's will?

Comment: Or I will add this `MyApp.Supervisor` to my `application.ex` children list?

Comment: If you need many worker starters, run a dedicated dynamic supervisor for them, and start them accordingly. `MyApp.Supervisor` should be surely supervised by the application.